# Create a watermark in a separate track with FFmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, quicktime, watermark

I have a PNG (alpha) file and a video file. I want to create a video in which the first track is the image and the second track is the video (PNG over video). The problem is that the PNG doesn't preserves transparency.

I need create a watermark (PNG) in a separate track with ffmpeg over video track.

```
ffmpeg -i base.mov -i logo.png -map 0 -map 1 output.mov
```

Answer (score 3):

The syntax to add a watermark is slightly different. You need video filters for that, which come bundled with FFmpeg already.

I'm not sure you can add a transparent watermark to a separate track. The reason is that the image itself (the PNG "stream") needs to be turned into an actual video track (e.g. with x264) – and since video encoders don't support transparency at this stage, you won't get a transparent image.

---

The following will add `logo.png` to `base.mov` in the upper right corner. You can use the following parameters to determine the position – in my example, I just placed it ten pixels away from the border:

- `main_w` (main video width)
- `main_h` (main video height)
- `overlay_w` (overlay video width)
- `overlay_h`  (overlay video hieght)

The filter command would then be:

```
movie='logo.png' [logo]; [in][logo] overlay=main_w-overlay_w-10:10 [out]
```

Turning this into a complete FFmpeg command:

```
ffmpeg -i base.mov -vf "movie='logo.png' [logo]; [in][logo] overlay=main_w-overlay_w-10:10 [out]" -c:v libx264 -crf 20 out.mov
```

The `-c:v libx264 -crf 20` parameters determine the output video codec and its quality (where CRF will probably be from 19 to 24, depending on which quality you want; lower is better).

There's a rather good blog post on that subject here: [How to watermark a video using FFmpeg](http://www.idude.net/index.php/how-to-watermark-a-video-using-ffmpeg/). It goes into positioning details.

Comment: Thank you very much. I needed the watermark is on a track (stream) separately in order to enable or disable it with quicktime pro.

Comment: You can try to create a combined video again after adding the overlay. `ffmpeg -i base.mov -i with-logo.mov -map 0 -map 1 -c:v copy -c:a copy output.mov`, but this will of course double the video size. I'm not aware of any other solution.